# Tesseract combine_lang_model "Null char" error

Tags: python, tesseract

I am following the instructions presented [here](https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2018/07/09/training-tesseract-models-from-scratch) to train Tesseract 4.0.

In the step to "Compiling the initial *.traineddata file", I entered the following command:

```
combine_lang_model --input_unicharset unicharset \
--script_dir /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata \
--output_dir . --pass_through_recoder --lang eng
```

I got the following error:

```
Config file is optional, continuing...
Failed to read data from: /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/eng/eng.config
Null char=93
```

My tessdata folder contains eng.traineddata, but does not contain eng.config . I have no idea how to obtain that file. Further, I have the "Null char=93" error. For reference, [this is my unicharset file](https://pastebin.com/1Fk5JXL8)

How can I resolve the above errors?

Comment: As stated in [tesseract documentation](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/langdata_lstm/tree/master/eng) `--script_dir` must point to the `langdata` (see [this](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/langdata_lstm/tree/master/eng)), not `tessdata`. If that change still won't fix the error - just create empty eng.config file in the eng langdata directory

Comment: @DmitriiZ. thank you for your reply. I am sorry that I missed the second line of error, I have added the same above. I changed the script-dir as you have mentioned as well. The above error still persists, but I think it is more to do with the "Null char" error.